# How can we get the userid of current login google account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to design a system using google spread sheet and app script where i want to validate the username of the account which is currently login to the system. How can i get the username from the system/browser so that it can give access to only those user whose google account is currently login to the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*It is possible to get the email address of the current logged in user to Google via Apps Script, but not the user logged into the* ***browser.***

#### More Information:

Google Apps Script has the `User` Class built-in, which can retrieve the current logged-in user's email address (and therefore their username as seen before the `@` in the email address). This has restrictions though, as noted by [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user):

> #### `getEmail()`
>
> Gets the user's email address, if available. If security policies do not allow access to the user's email address, this method returns a blank string. The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple `onOpen(e)` or `onEdit(e)` trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user). However, these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or belongs to the same Google Workspace domain as the user.
>
> **Return**
>
> `String` — The user's email's address, or a blank string if security policies do not allow access to the user's email address.

This is the only method available to obtain a username. Its usage guidance is as follows:

```js
// Log the email address of the person running the script.
let email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
Logger.log(email);
```

**Remember:** This can only retrieve the user logged in to their Google Account at [accounts.google.com](https://accounts.google.com). This ***will not*** retrieve information from the local browser, and ***it is not possible to do so using Apps Script.***

#### References:

- [Class User | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user)

Comment: I tried using this code but I'm getting blank value for emailid

Comment: @UjjwalChauhan Did you read my answer or just copy the code? It is expected to return a blank string when security policies disallow the email to be retrieved. You can't do anything about that.

Comment: @ Rafa Guillermo Thanks a lot your solution really helped me to achieve what i wanted. now i want that value to be stored in javascript variable but I'm getting undefined value.

Comment: @UjjwalChauhan whqat is coming up as undefined? The variable `email`? Can you provide your error and under what circumstanced you see it?

Comment: In .gs file
function retrieveEmail()
{
  //Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  return Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
}
In Html File
var email=google.script.run.retrieveEmail();
window.alert(email);  //output: undefined

Comment: That isn't how `google.script.run` works - you need a success handler to deal with a return value you can't just use a `return` statement from the Apps Script side of things... but this is another question entirely. Check out [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) for more information.